# Puppet for Windows and Powershell Recipes

Tags: powershell, puppet, recipe

I am trying to set some powershell inline cmdlets within puppet recipes in order to install other msi packages and powershell scripts.

```
class ps{
    #http://docs.puppetlabs.com/windows/running.html

    exec {'executionpolicy':
        path => 'C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0', 
        command => 'Powershell.exe "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Verbose"',
        logoutput => true
        }

    exec {'psremoting':
        path => 'C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0', 
        command => 'Powershell.exe "Enable-PSRemoting -Force -Verbose"',
        logoutput => true,
        require => Exec["executionpolicy"]
        } 
    exec {'psmemory':
        path => 'C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0', 
        command => 'Powershell.exe "Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048"',
        logoutput => true,
        require => [Exec["psremoting"],Exec["executionpolicy"]]
    }
}
```

I am getting different errors and i was thinking on changing the approach and add those inline cmdlets into a .ps1 script. Any recommendations on running powershell inline scripts as puppet recipes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this powershell puppet modules to help you

http://forge.puppetlabs.com/joshcooper/powershell/0.0.2

This work better